Video autoplay on next slide
So i have a small slider build with UIkit.
If the second slide is a video, it would be important to only start the video when clicking on the next slide. That way, the video is at the beginning when a user sees it.
That seems to work when embedding a YouTube Video like here:
https://codepen.io/honk007/pen/OJeBrNp
But when doing the same with a Vimeo resource like this one:
https://player.vimeo.com/video/691403770?api=1&background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1

The video is already playing. I tried all kind of parameters but no success.
